# Properly enable AccessibilityChecks for multi-file test suite

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, accessibility

I'm trying to wrap  my head around the proper way to set up Android Espresso's `AccessibilityChecks`. Documentation suggests I just call `AccessibilityChecks.enable()` in a `@Before` setup method. The problem is, if you have more than one test in that class, the second test run will throw an exception warning that `AccessibilityChecks` is already enabled. You can fix this by instead calling it in a `@BeforeClass` static setup method. However, if you have another test that should have `AccessbililtyChecks` enabled, you'll get the same error. `AccessibilityChecks.enable()` creates a **global** view assertion that can't be disabled or removed, as far as I can tell.

My current workaround is to have an Espresso test that runs before all the other ones (`AAA_AccessibilityTest.java`), and I don't enable it anywhere else.

The problem with that is if I'm focusing on a particular test set, the Accessibility Checks won't run, because that test isn't included.

Maybe someone from Android can weigh in here, but I haven't been able to find any working examples on Github or elsewhere that shows this being used in a non-trivial test suite.

The intent of `AccessibilityChecks.enable()` is awesome, but the implementation seems completely broken without a way to `disable()` them after we `enable()` them. Am I missing something? How can I use this in a reliable and sane way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable it in a custom test runner (in Java):

```
public class AccessibilityChecksTestRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {
  static {
    AccessibilityChecks.enable();
  }
}
```

or in Kotlin

```
 class AccessibilityChecksTestRunner : AndroidJUnitRunner() {
    init {
       AccessibilityChecks.enable()
    }
 }
```

Use in `build.gradle`:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.AccessibilityChecksTestRunner"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but in case anyone wants to use a `TestRule` instead of a custom `TestRunner`, you can do the following:

Create a `TestRule`:

```kotlin
class AccessibilityChecksTestRule : TestWatcher() {

    @BeforeClass
    fun enableAccessibilityChecks() {
        AccessibilityChecks.enable()
    }
}
```

In your test class:

```kotlin
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class YourInstrumentationTest {

    @get:Rule val accessibilityChecksTestRule = AccessibilityChecksTestRule()

    …
}
```

Finally, in `build.gradle`, you'd use the default `androidx` `TestRunner`:

```
testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```